# IF/THEN statement producing syntax error in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a very basic `IF` statement written that will be a part of a trigger, but when I try to run the query I receive a syntax error:

```
IF (STR_TO_DATE('09/29/2017','%m/%d/%Y') > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN
    SELECT * FROM apikeys;
END IF;
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 1

I'm using MySQL 5.6

**UPDATE**: I now understand that `IF`/`THEN` statements can only be stored in procedures like triggers and are unable to be executed in this manner normally. Is there any way of knowing a trigger will be successful before implementing the new code into a live system? This trigger specifically controls a text messaging queue that fires SMS through Twilio, so I really cannot afford to guess and check.

Comment: `IF... THEN ....END IF` is only usable in stored procedures, triggers, etc...

Comment: So what would be used for a normal query? `CASE`?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procedural logic in MySQL is only usable in stored procedures, triggers, events, etc... You cannot conditionally execute a query outside of those places (or client code obviously); the closest you can get is to make the IF's condition a part of the query's WHERE conditions. You still get a result set, but it will be empty.

```
SELECT * 
FROM apikeys
WHERE STR_TO_DATE('09/29/2017','%m/%d/%Y') > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
;
```

Edit: In situations where you absolutely positively need procedure logic; you can create a stored procedure with it, execute that, and then drop the procedure.

---

Edit2:

> Is there any way of knowing a trigger will be successful before
>   implementing the new code into a live system?

Seems, obvious but the best way to know is to run it on a **test** system. If that is not an option for some reason, as long as you are not using the `NEW` or `OLD` features of triggers you should be able to copy it into the body of a test procedure and run that instead...but you also won't get warned if you have queries that attempt to modify the table the trigger is on.

Comment: This snippet of code WILL be stored in a trigger, so if there is any way to ensure what I wrote would be correct, I would like to keep the same `IF -> THEN` logic. I will adjust my question accordingly

Comment: Definitely faster.  than the over engineered cross join I tried.

Comment: @Jodo1992 As far as I know, you can't really SELECT in a trigger. I mean you _could_; but then I'd expect a single result SELECT with assignments to variables, or a  CURSOR, to be used. Either way, I don't think a trigger can return a result set.

Comment: @xQbert we all have those moments. ;)

Comment: @Uueerdo you absolutely can use SELECT in triggers. I do it all the time

Comment: @Jodo1992 where do the results end up? Do they actually come back as resultsets from the insert query? If you do an INSERT...SELECT, to you get resultsets for every row inserted?